# Do python-request sessions detect when a page automatically refreshes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, queue

I've recently been experimenting with using the request module in Python for webscraping and have a question about when a site automatically refreshes.  For example, if I sent a request to a website and had to wait in a queue because the website had too many people trying to access it at once, how would the requests session handle eventually being redirected to the site?

Would I be able to do something like:

```
import requests, time
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('www.example.com')
passed = 0
while passed == 0:
    if 'passed' in r.text:
        print('passed queue!')
        passed = 1
    else: 
        print('still in queue')
        time.sleep(60)
```

Or would I have to do another GET request in order to determine if I passed the queue or not and do something like:

```
import requests, time
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('http://www.example.com')
passed = 0
while passed == 0:
    if 'passed' in r.text:
        print('passed queue!')
        passed = 1
    else: 
        print('still in queue')
        time.sleep(60)
        r = s.get('http://www.example.com')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests doesn't interpret the response beyond handling the `Location` header for redirects. If the page uses a `<meta>` tag or JavaScript to perform the refresh, you'll have to handle it.

If you want to act like a real browser at the expense of speed and higher resource utilization, use a headless browser like Selenium.